# has been finished or are finished past perfect tense

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to ask my niece whether her exams are over or not.

Should I say:

> Your exams have been finished or not

Or

> Your exams are finished or not

Past perfect is used to describe completed action in past which has impact on the present.

Answer (score 1):

You could better say it like: "Are your exams finished?" or less common but still correct "Have your exams finished?" (because the way you are saying is called 'declarative questions', which would look odd here.)

You could also (more commonly) say it like this:"Are you done with your exams?"